# JPA: fetch with only a few attributes

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

If I were fetching records from a DB, using a `SELECT` query for example, and need only a few of the attributes (columns), I would do something like:

```
SELECT name FROM TENANT WHERE id=1;
```

**Question 1: how can we do the same in JPA?**

This is how it is done now which fetches all attributes:

```
@PersistenceContext
javax.persistence.EntityManager em;
...
em.find(Tenant, 1);
```

How can we fetch only `name` field `WHERE tenant.id=1`?

**Question 2: how can fetch only a few attributes when there are child classes?**

```
public class Tenant implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant")
    private List<Department> departments;

    ...
}

public class Department implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Tenant
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="TenantId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Tenant tenant;

    ...
}
```

How to fetch only `name` fields of both `Tenant` and `Department` `WHERE tenant.id=1`?`

Comment: You've tried JPA 2.1 EntityGraphs?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But, I am not sure if it meets the need. **EntityGraph** loads specified attributes eagerly and others lazily. Which means, the lazy attributes will still be fetched when they are referenced. The entity read from DB will be mapped to a DTO through a mapper. The mapper will try to map all the entity attributes - at which time the lazy attributes will be fetched from DB. This is not what is needed. The client requests only for `name` and the returned DTO should have only `name` filled. Other attributes should remain `null`.

Comment: And in the question there is no mention of a DTO.

Comment: *"returned DTO should have only name filled. Other attributes should remain null."*--how do you imagine `em.find()` or whatever query to look like? How should `EntityManager` know which particular properties you need? I could believe in lazy loading getters, in analogy to getters for nested entities and collections, but setting some properties to null when they are not null in DB, will break JPA nature.

Comment: I understand setting null when not null in DB does not seem right. The requirement is simple - fetch only required attributes. This is easily doable if we use direct SQL. The question is how can we do the same with JPA call or query. My expectation ix to specify the list of attributes to read through a property and invoke JPA call/query. Lazy loading solution could work if we can check the attribute is not loaded and then the mapper will not map those attributes. Is it possible to check if an attribute is not loaded yet and will be loaded lazily?

Comment: Currently JPA and popular implementations don't introduce such functionality. Maybe some exotic implementations do

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by JPQL (aka HQL):

First case:

```
List<String> names = em.createQuery("select t.name from Tenant t where t.id = :id")
                       .setParameter("id", 1)
                       .getResultList();
```

Second case the same, but query will be:

```
"select d.name from Department d where d.tenant.id = :id"
```

`getResultList()` can be replaced by `getSingleResult()`, but it will throw an exception if such element don't exist, so must be wrapped with try-catch.

Comment: I think you missed the point. We don't query for child entity separately. em.find will return the parent Tenant along with referenced child Department. JPA automatically issues the queries for parent and child and constructs the mapped Tenant class. So the issue here is, only 'name' attribute of child Department should be retrieved without we having to issue another query for it.

Comment: @gammay yes I did miss the point. If you already have the entity retrieved by `em.find()`, why don't you just get properties you need from the result? Of course, when you try to get some property of lazy-fetching nested entity it will be queried and fetched--such abstraction is the main convinience JPA is designed for.

Comment: So far, there is no way in JPA to mark scalar properties to be fetched lazily, nor to be set to null for some specific queries. If you need only particular properties to be fetched, use other mechanism such as jpql, criteria query, or even plain old sql.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, yes we can let JPA load all properties and map only required ones. This is the way we are doing currently. The issue is performance - the complete entity travels up the stack and then not-required properties are discarded - which is inefficient. A better way to do it is not to read those properties from the DB at all. This is the motivation for the question.